# Simplified wireframe on top of mesh?

Tags: edit-mode

I've seen some blender streams and i frequently noticed creators interacting with a wireframe that was a bit bigger than the mesh itself, that wireframe was simpler than the actual mesh wireframe (which he toggled to the normal wireframe sometimes), seemed like it worked almost like he was sculpting instead of using edit mode, with multiple vertices following that wireframe. Some of them had even just 32,64 vertices when the actual wireframe had over 12k.
I want to know what it was because i think it would be really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are talking about Multiresolution modifier:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/multiresolution.html

Comment: There was no modifiers active besides armature and subdivision surface